# Effectiveness of Throws on the Ground and Standing Up (Judo, BJJ etc)

Tags: brazilian-jiu-jitsu, judo, aikido, streetfight, throwing

Next year it's going to be a little more throwing-oriented year in my club (although we're still going to mix ground fighting and stand up fighting, submissions etc).

My question is: how practical and effective are throws and why? Against punching and kicking? On the ground? In the streets?

Appears like they're pretty great for getting dominant position, sometimes they're even fight enders? Throws seem like a logical transmission between stand up and ground fighting.

Have a nice day and happy throwing!

[image]

Comment: This question is massively over broad thus voted to close it. It needs to be narrowed down to be answerable in anything shorter than a book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Throwing is a very effective part of the martial arts arsenal.

- Many people actually unbalance themselves when striking or kicking. It can be much easier to punish them for this by throwing than with counterstriking. Kicking to the head, for example, may make sense when your opponent is not allowed to throw you, but it becomes very dangerous when they can throw you.
- A common defense against striking is to close distance and clinch. Throwing allows you to continue attacking immediately if your opponent closes to negate your striking, or if you are closing.
- Taking falls is inherently dangerous. In most training settings, a throwing practitioner tries to land a trained receiving partner in a manner to prevent injury onto a flat, padded surface. In combat, you do not try to protect the receiver; you throw onto their head or try to knock the wind out of them. If landing on uneven concrete, do not expect to get up without injury. Think about how many people injure themselves when they slip and fall, and imagine how much worse that gets if someone else is adding momentum or lands on top.
- Throwing is not normally practiced in groundfighting, or at least the techniques are no longer called throwing.

Do not expect to be able to  exclusively throw. If you watch high-level judo, for example, competitors are able to stall out long portions of matches without getting thrown. If you want to throw people, you want to work it seamless into your fighting strategy so that your striking sets up your throws, and your missed throws set up your strikes.